# Creating php backend alternative to poedit

Tags: php, translation, gettext

I was just wondering if i can find php backend which can be used as alternative to poedit to enter translations.

Sometimes we need update view files directly to live server and its painful to download all source to local machine and generate .po files and translate them using poedit and upload again. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It's not PHP, but there is Transifex, in both [download](http://www.transifex.org/) and [hosted](http://www.transifex.net/) form. </shamelessplug>

Answer (score 1):

i am using FTP for uploading and downloading PHP files as well as folders, so in that case if you want to edit/update only some of the source in the FTP you can right click on file name where you get the option for "View/edit" which can be open in any of your editor and its still connected with FTP so whenever you done change in that file and save it will automatically save on your live server too.

So if your query what i have understood then you can use my answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually you got me wrong. It is not about editing a file in server. It is about editing translation files, specifically .po file without using any standard po editor, instead using php backend.

I got rid of .po format, rather using tmx(translation memory exchange) format now as xml are easier to maintain and made a php backend myself for managing translations to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WordPress for my website. There is a plugin for WordPress that can edit po-files and generate mo-files.

CodeStyling Localization (plugin for WordPress):

[image: Screenshot CodeStyling Localization]

http://www.code-styling.de/english/development/wordpress-plugin-codestyling-localization-en

Unfortunately, if you're not using WordPress you have nothing.